# copy and paste filtered visible cells from one column to another column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have an auto filter on my excel file activated in my macro. When I run my code, I got the following error message:

> Run time error 438, Object does not support this property or method

I tried to run my macro step by step via <kbd>F8</kbd>, it seems that this line below generated this error:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Paste
```

I want that my macro execute the following action:

- All my visible filtered lines in column AA are copied in column K
- All my visible filtered lines in column J are replaced by the value “J0”

If someone could help me, it would be great.

```
Sub fuelstep4ArvalBIF()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Range("A1").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter

  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$3000").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=Array( _
  "21.00", "21", "19.00", "19", "5.50", "5.5", "13.00", "13"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

  Call  FirstVisibleCellAA
  Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy  Call FirstVisibleCellK
  Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Paste Call FirstVisibleCellJ 
  ActiveCell.Value = "J0" ActiveCell.Copy Range(ActiveCell, 
  ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Paste 
End Sub 

Sub FirstVisibleCellK()
  With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
   Range("K" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
  End With
End Sub 

Sub FirstVisibleCellAA()
  With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range Range( _ 
  "AA" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
  End With
End Sub 

Sub FirstVisibleCellJ() With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
  Range("J" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
End With End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Rawrplus, excuse me for the unintended edit after yours (while you did a much better job too). OT: You might want to start by avoiding the use of `.Select`, `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveCell` and declare variables instead. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) thread for some nice explaination.

Comment: @JvdV I believe there should be an option to rollback, but oh well, it's fine. :)

Comment: I've had issues pasting to a range if the copy range contains a different number of cells.  Generally, you paste to a single cell, and the data you paste will start in that cell and use as much space as it needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately I do not manage to do what I want yet…

What I want to do is to copy and paste the datas from my columns AA to column K (only the visible cells of my activesheet after applying the filter according to my code below)

When I run my macro I got the following error message below on my line "Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy WS.r":
"compile error, Method or data member not found"


Here please find my code below:

Comment: Sub fuelstep4ArvalBIF()
            Dim WS As Worksheet
            Dim r As Range
            Set WS = ActiveSheet
            Set r = Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          Range("A1").Select
             Selection.AutoFilter
     WS.Range("$A$1:$AF$3000").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "21.00", "21", "19.00", "19", "5.50", "5.5", "13.00", "13"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
     Call    FirstVisibleCellAA
     Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy WS.r
End Sub

Comment: Sub FirstVisibleCellAA()
  With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range Range( _ 
  "AA" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
  End With
End Sub

Comment: I finally managed to solve my problem with myself with this Code, I am very happy...

Comment: I finally managed to solve my problem by myself with this Code below:ub fuelstep4ArvalBIF()
'
' fuelstep2ALDBIF
'

'
             Dim r1, r2, WS, myMultipleRange As Range
       
     Set WS = ActiveSheet
           
            Set r1 = Range("AA:AA").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Set r2 = Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          Range("A1").Select
             Selection.AutoFilter

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$3000").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "21.00", "21", "19.00", "19", "5.50", "5.5", "13.00", "13"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
     
 
   
    myMultipleRange.FillLeft
   End sub